# How do I have a game board updated based on input?

Tags: python

I am a beginner teaching myself programming and python and my first project is a game called shut the box. There is a board with numbers 1 - 10.
Player rolls two dice and the sum of the two dice has to be taken off the board. For example, if the sum is 10. You can take out (10),(1,9),(2,3,5), etc. All the combinations for the sum is available and player chooses one. Once the numbers are chosen they are off the board. I am stuck on how to have the input of numbers change the board.
This is my current code.

```
Board = {'one': '1', 'two':'2', 'three': '3', 'four': '4', \
        'five':'5', 'six': '6', 'seven': '7', 'eight':'8', 'nine': '9', \
        'ten': '10'}

#printing the visual of the board, starts with showing each integer 1 thru 10

def displayBoard():
    print(Board['one'] + '|' + Board['two'] + '|' + Board['three'] + '|' \
          + Board['four'] + '|' + Board['five'] + '|' + Board['six'] + '|' \
          + Board['seven'] + '|' + Board['eight'] + '|' + Board['nine'] + '|' \
          + Board['ten'] + '|')



def playgame():
     displayBoard




   import random

   diceRoll = random.randint(1, 6) + random.randint(1,6)

   print('Welcome! Here is your board, let\'s get started.')
   displayBoard(Board)

   print('To begin, roll the pair of dice by typing \'r\' then press Enter''.')


   rollOne = input()


   if rollOne == 'r':
       print('The sum of your two rolls is ' + str(diceRoll) + '.  Now choose which \
   numbers to remove from the board.')
       print('Here\'s the board again, you can type a single number, or multiple \
   numbers separated by a commma to remove them from the board. Then press Enter.')
       displayBoard(Board)

   newBoard = input()

   if str(newBoard) in Board:
       print('yes')
   else:
       print('no')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're several issues that need to be resolved before answering your question:

1. It is considered the best practice to put the import statement at the beginning of the program. This is so that we can better manage the libraries we imported.
2. There's actually no need to use a dictionary to convert from English numbers to numeric ones in `Board`. I'd suggest we just store the numbers so that `Board` can be easier to work with. So now `Board` would look like:

```py
Board = set(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

where `set` is a data structure that can add or discard elements faster than `list`. Since the numbers here are continuous integers, there's a better way to write them:

```py
Board = set(range(1, 11))
```

3. `displayBoard` needs to be changed so that it can deal with a board with removed numbers. Also based on what you wrote in `playgame`, `displayBoard` should take a parameter which is the board of the game. Combining what I just said, `displayBoard` now should be:

```py
def displayBoard(Board):
    for n in Board:
        print(n, end='|')
    print()
```

If you want to go fancy you can do this in one line:

```py
def displayBoard(Board):
    print('|'.join([str(n) for n in Board]))
```

Here `join` is a method of string. It takes an iterable(things like `list`, `tuple`, `dict`, `set` etc) and prints each element out with '|' as the separator. The list-like expression in `join` is called list comprehension. What it's doing is converting all the numbers into strings and storing it into a new list, which is passed into `join`.

Now let's go back to the question you asked. To remove the numbers given by the user you need to first separate those numbers with `,` and convert them into integers. You can do it like this:

```py
newBoard = input() # Assume user typed '2,3,4'
numbers = [int(i) for i in newBoard.split(',')] # [2, 3, 4]
```

Next you need to check if these numbers are still in `Board`. If they do then you need to check if they add up to `diceRoll`. And if they do then you can iterate over `numbers` and just discard each number in `Board`:

```py
if sum(numbers) != diceRoll:
    print("Your numbers don't add up to " + diceRoll)
else:
    for n in numbers:
        if n not in Board:
            print(n + " is not in board.")
            return # Abort playgame()

    for i in numbers:
        Board.discard(i)
    print("Your new board is: ")
    displayBoard(Board)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have made changes but now the game stops after I choose the numbers. If you can help clarify I would appreciate it.

Comment: @Radwan Can you share your current code? You can upload your code to GitHub and share a link here

Comment: Yes of course, I will.

Comment: This is the link https://github.com/Radwan2001/Shut-The-Box/blob/main/Shut%20The%20Box

Comment: Alright, so the reason it stops after you enter the number is because you didn't call `playgame` to process the inputs. Also, I believe you need to move all the code below and include line 11 into `playgame` and you need to loop the whole thing for it to work like a game.

Comment: Is it possible for you to show me? I am confused on how to do it.

Comment: Just submitted a pull request to your repository. You can take a look

Comment: This works perfectly. How would make it so that, if the numbers remaining on the board cant be used to make up the sum of the rolls, the game ends as a loss?

Comment: You have to check all possible groups of numbers players can enter and see if any of them can add up to the number rolled.

Comment: How would I code it that so when there is no more numbers left on the board player wins.

Comment: That's easy: you just check if `len(Board)` equals 0.

Comment: I changed the code on github if you would be willing to look at it. https://github.com/Radwan2001/Shut-The-Box/blob/main/Shut%20The%20Box                I was thinking of making it so that the player can input 'n' if they cant find numbers to equal the diceRoll. I dont know where to put that though.

Comment: You should put it after line 30 and check if `newBoard` equals `'n'`. Also remember to break the loop when the player wins/loses

Comment: @Radwan BTW if you think my answer is helpful please consider marking my answer as accepted. It would be very much appreciated.

Comment: When I put it after line 30 and run the code. I get an error after I type n in the game.

Comment: Can you update your code to github? I cannot debug for you if I don't see the code

Comment: I updated the code on Github. Also where would I put the check board == 0

Comment: It's `len(board) == 0` and it should be put at the end of the loop. Also, the reason you get an error is that you didn't break the loop when the player wins/loses. If you don't the game will act as if nothing happened and will continue the game.

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind showing it on Github?